# Get all the indices of unique elements

Tags: r, text-mining, data-processing

I have a dataset with 500 000 entries. Each entry in it has a userId and a productId. I want to get all userIds corresponding to each distinct productIds. But the list is to huge that none of the following method works for me, it's going very slow. Is there any faster solution.

**Using `lapply`: (Problem: Traversing the whole rpid list for each uniqPids elements)**

```
orderedIndx <- lapply(uniqPids, function(x){
    which(rpid %in% x)
})
names(orderedIndx) <- uniqPids
#Looking for indices with each unique productIds
```

**Using `For` loop:**

```
  orderedIndx <- list()
  for(j in 1:length(rpid)){
    existing <- length(orderedIndx[rpid[j]])
    orderedIndx[rpid[j]][existing + 1] <- j
  }
```

**Sample Data:**

```
ruid[1:10]
# [1] "a3sgxh7auhu8gw" "a1d87f6zcve5nk" "abxlmwjixxain"  "a395borc6fgvxv" "a1uqrsclf8gw1t" "adt0srk1mgoeu" 
 [7] "a1sp2kvkfxxru1" "a3jrgqveqn31iq" "a1mzyo9tzk0bbi" "a21bt40vzccyt4"

rpid[1:10]
# [1] "b001e4kfg0" "b001e4kfg0" "b000lqoch0" "b000ua0qiq" "b006k2zz7k" "b006k2zz7k" "b006k2zz7k" "b006k2zz7k"
 [9] "b000e7l2r4" "b00171apva"
```

Output should be like:

```
b001e4kfg0 -> a3sgxh7auhu8gw, a1d87f6zcve5nk
b000lqoch0 -> abxlmwjixxain
b000ua0qiq -> a395borc6fgvxv
b006k2zz7k -> a1uqrsclf8gw1t, adt0srk1mgoeu, a1sp2kvkfxxru1, a3jrgqveqn31iq
b000e7l2r4 -> a1mzyo9tzk0bbi
b00171apva -> a21bt40vzccyt4
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the data set and your desired output? It's not clear to me from your code what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Aaron yes, i am adding some sample data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what type of output you want, or how many rows you have in your dataset, but I'd suggest 3 versions and you can chose the one you like. First version uses `dplyr` and character values for your variables. I expect this to be slow if you have millions of rows. Second version uses `dplyr` but factor variables. I expect this to be faster than the previous one. Third version uses `data.table`. I expect this to be equally fast, or faster than the second version.

```
library(dplyr)

ruid = 
c("a3sgxh7auhu8gw", "a1d87f6zcve5nk", "abxlmwjixxain",  "a395borc6fgvxv",
  "a1uqrsclf8gw1t", "adt0srk1mgoeu", "a1sp2kvkfxxru1", "a3jrgqveqn31iq",
  "a1mzyo9tzk0bbi", "a21bt40vzccyt4")

rpid =
c("b001e4kfg0", "b001e4kfg0", "b000lqoch0", "b000ua0qiq", "b006k2zz7k",
  "b006k2zz7k", "b006k2zz7k", "b006k2zz7k", "b000e7l2r4", "b00171apva")

### using dplyr and character values
dt = data.frame(rpid, ruid, stringsAsFactors = F)

dt %>%
  group_by(rpid) %>%
  do(data.frame(list_ruids = paste(c(.$ruid), collapse=", "))) %>%
  ungroup

#         rpid                                                    list_ruids
#        (chr)                                                         (chr)
# 1 b000e7l2r4                                                a1mzyo9tzk0bbi
# 2 b000lqoch0                                                 abxlmwjixxain
# 3 b000ua0qiq                                                a395borc6fgvxv
# 4 b00171apva                                                a21bt40vzccyt4
# 5 b001e4kfg0                                a3sgxh7auhu8gw, a1d87f6zcve5nk
# 6 b006k2zz7k a1uqrsclf8gw1t, adt0srk1mgoeu, a1sp2kvkfxxru1, a3jrgqveqn31iq


# ----------------------------------

### using dplyr and factor values
dt = data.frame(rpid, ruid, stringsAsFactors = T)

dt %>%
  group_by(rpid) %>%
  do(data.frame(list_ruids = paste(c(levels(dt$ruid)[.$ruid]), collapse=", "))) %>%
  ungroup

#         rpid                                                    list_ruids
#       (fctr)                                                         (chr)
# 1 b000e7l2r4                                                a1mzyo9tzk0bbi
# 2 b000lqoch0                                                 abxlmwjixxain
# 3 b000ua0qiq                                                a395borc6fgvxv
# 4 b00171apva                                                a21bt40vzccyt4
# 5 b001e4kfg0                                a3sgxh7auhu8gw, a1d87f6zcve5nk
# 6 b006k2zz7k a1uqrsclf8gw1t, adt0srk1mgoeu, a1sp2kvkfxxru1, a3jrgqveqn31iq


# -------------------------------------

library(data.table)

### using data.table
dt = data.table(rpid, ruid)

dt[, list(list_ruids = paste(c(ruid), collapse=", ")), by = rpid]

#          rpid                                                    list_ruids
# 1: b001e4kfg0                                a3sgxh7auhu8gw, a1d87f6zcve5nk
# 2: b000lqoch0                                                 abxlmwjixxain
# 3: b000ua0qiq                                                a395borc6fgvxv
# 4: b006k2zz7k a1uqrsclf8gw1t, adt0srk1mgoeu, a1sp2kvkfxxru1, a3jrgqveqn31iq
# 5: b000e7l2r4                                                a1mzyo9tzk0bbi
# 6: b00171apva                                                a21bt40vzccyt4
```

Comment: Nice :) I will consider the last one. It works perfectly

Comment: Why the last one? :-) Also, my assumption was that you don't have any duplicate rows. You can create your own check in the beginning (to remove duplicates) before you continue with that process.

Comment: Oh. I picked it because first of all you said it may be faster than the other and also I like data.table's syntax. It looks easier to read :P

Answer (score 2):

It seems perhaps you're just looking for `split`?

```
split(seq_along(rpid), rpid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have tidy data in a dataframe? Then you can do this.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  select(productId, userId) %>%
  distinct
```